# adding nested HasTraits properties to a TraitsUI TView

Tags: python, traits, enthought, traitsui

i have a *main* HasTraits class which contains several Instance's of other HasTraits objects. I would like to define an Item in the view of the `main` object which points to a trait of a nested object. for example:

```
class Person(HasTraits):
    name = String()

class Pet(HasTraits):
    name = String()


class Family(HasTraits):
    father = Instance(Person,())
    dog = Instance(Pet,())

    view = View(
        Item('father.name'),
        Item('dog.name'),
        )
```

is this possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody named Alex asked this question 1 week ago by email, and we responded:

```
view = View(
    Item('object.father.name'),
    Item('object.dog.name'),
    )
```

See the bottom of http://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/traitsui_user_manual/advanced_view.html#multi-object-views

If you are the same Alex, you might want to tweak your spam filters (enthought.com and enthought.zendesk.com)

Comment: thanks, and you are correct, the gmail spam-filter snagged it.

Comment: i believe that my objects are not independent, as required by that solution. the above  example is trivial but in the real application the object represented by Family contains its own functionality which  requires information from Person and  Pet. I want to retain the Family class, but simply tweak the views of Person and Pet.

Comment: Are you mentioning this because there is a problem? The "object" syntax is particular to the View. For Python object references, you can proceed normally -- e.g. within a method of Family, refer to self.father.name. Does this help?

Comment: yes your solution works, thanks!  the docs had a different usage. also, my indention was incorrect in the original question and has been fixed.