# views on Nested HasTraits object

Tags: python, enthought, traitsui

I am having trouble getting the views to work as expected, using nested `HasTraits`. For example:

```
class A(HasTraits):
    b= Any()

...
view = View(...
    Item('b', style='custom')
...
```

I would like to import the class of b and assign it to A,

```
from some_other_mod import B 
# B HasTraits also
a = A(b = B())
```

This works, but the view of `B()` does not display within `a`, when i `a.configure_traits()`

(Note this is related, but not identical to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566477/adding-nested-hastraits-properties-to-a-traitsui-tview))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an `InstanceEditor`.

```
class A(HasTraits):
    b = Instance(HasTraits)
    traits_view = View( Item('b', editor=InstanceEditor(), style='custom') )

class B(HasTraits):
    c = Int
    traits_view = View( Item('c') )
```

Note that an `Instance` trait uses an `InstanceEditor` by default. An `Any` trait by default uses a `TextEditor` instead.